# Grey distortion when rendering with cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, mesh

So I’m following the donut tutorial and when I go to render it in cycles the icing mesh renders with some strange grey distortion on it. Anyone know what could be causing this, and why its not rendering as just plain white? Thanks[image]

Comment: Hi :). Looks like a duplicate donut right underneath :))

Comment: I checked and it looks like there is one donut. even when I move the icing mesh away from the donut it still renders with that weird texture on it.